# Select All row where same name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like

```
name  M1    m2   Tot
a      20   30    50
b      10   20    30    
a      20   10    30
a      30   15    45
```

from this table .i want to get table as

```
name   Tot1  Tot2  Tot3
a      50     30    45
b      30     0      0
```

how to get like that? How to write sql query? or any other way?

Comment: why are you tagging c#? which sql are you using?

Comment: I think you will need dynamic SQL for this, since the row numbers corresponding to `a` and `b` could be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: It would help if you could format your data so that we could see the structure

Comment: @ Coderchu..sorry for tagging c#, i am using ms sql 2012

Comment: @user3172066 So you want the first row of each name (first row of a, first row of b, etc....) ?

Comment: i try with select query SELECT name, max(Total) from tablename group by name

Comment: Please explain how tot1, tot2 and tot3 are calculated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name first, second and third value of each name. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (name VARCHAR(1), M1 INT,   m2 INT,  Tot INT)
DECLARE @MAXOBS INT
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('a',      20,   30,    50),
('b',      10,   20,    30),   
('a',      20,   10,    30),
('a',      30,   15,    45)



 SELECT NAME,TOT1,TOT2,TOT3, TOT1+TOT2+TOT3 AS TOTAL
FROM
(
SELECT  NAME, 
        ISNULL([1],0) AS TOT1,
        ISNULL([2],0) AS TOT2,
        ISNULL([3],0) AS TOT3
FROM 
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) RN,
        NAME,
        TOT
FROM    T
) S
PIVOT (MAX(TOT) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PVT
) T
```

If you think there will be more than 3 rows per name you will need dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanq @P.Salmon.. I need from Select . So i ignore Create query. Indeed you save my day.

Comment: @P.Salmon->how can i add one more column as sum?

Comment: Edited to add row total

Comment: Sir.. can i extract this query to find those who are having sum value between 10 and 50? I tried by using temp table. but i want this one also in this query..

Comment: Just add WHERE TOT1+TOT2+TOT3 BETWEEN 10 AND 150 on a new line after ) T

Comment: i try with T where T.CentreExam='AAA' and T.DateExam BETWEEN '2016-07-15' and '2016-07-28' .It works fine to get data between two dates. but need to extend this query to get topper basis of average for each exam center..? can u help for this only? please its urgent..

Answer (score 0):

Code below has been tested and works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("M1", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("M2", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Tot", typeof(int));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"a", 20, 30, 50});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"b", 10, 20, 30});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"a", 20, 10, 30});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"a", 30, 15, 45});

            var groups = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("name"))
                .ToList();

            int maxGroup = groups.Select(x => x.Count()).Max();

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            for (int i = 1; i <= maxGroup; i++)
            {
                dt2.Columns.Add("Tot" + i.ToString());
            }
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                string name = group.Key;
                DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
                newRow["name"] = name; 
                int numItems = group.Count();
                int[] totals = group.Select(x => x.Field<int>("Tot")).ToArray();
                for (int i = 1; i <= maxGroup; i++)
                {
                    if (i <= numItems)
                    {
                        newRow[i] = totals[i - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newRow[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: User wants an SQL Query

Comment: Then you need to use a PIVOT TABLE : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and works 100% and produces the results you want exactly (It is dynamic also) and it is not limited to 3 totals

The below creates a temp table, creates a dynamic number of columns based on the max
number occurrence of a value of a specific column. Then populates these columns dynamically. Basically, you're creating columns out of rows for specific column values.

**You need to change all occurances of `T1` with your actual table name.**

You can create a Stored Procedure out of this:

```
DECLARE @MAXCOUNT INT = (SELECT MAX(R.c) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM T1 GROUP BY NAME) R)
DECLARE @NUMBER_OF_NAMES INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM T1) R)

PRINT @MAXCOUNT;
PRINT @NUMBER_OF_NAMES

SELECT DISTINCT NAME INTO #TEMP FROM T1

DECLARE @I INT = 0;
WHILE(@I < @MAXCOUNT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TOTINDEX INT = @I + 1;
    DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ALTER TABLE #TEMP ADD TOT' 
                                + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @TOTINDEX) + ' INT';
    EXEC (@QUERY);


    DECLARE @UPDATE NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'UPDATE T 
     SET TOT' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @TOTINDEX) + 
' = (SELECT TOP 1 TOTAL FROM ( SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Name = T.Name ORDER BY NAME OFFSET ' 
     + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @I) + ' ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY ) R ) FROM #TEMP T';

     PRINT @UPDATE

     SET @I = @I + 1;

     EXEC(@UPDATE);
END

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Results:

```
NAME    TOT1    TOT2    TOT3
a        50      30      45
b        30     NULL     NULL
```

Comment: when try with this. it shows error like.. Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 13
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 14
Must declare the scalar variable "@QUERY".

Comment: @user3172066 try the edited answer now. Be aware if you have an error while testing you need to manually execute `DROP TABLE #TEMP`

Comment: Thanq so much for ur valuable response. this is not working dear,.. @P.Salmon's answer is working for me..

Comment: @user3172066 works perfectly on my machine, for same table structure and same data.

Answer (score -1):

This actually increased the redundancy in the table and violates the 1NF form. One solution is that, you can have one more table.

```
select total from table1, table2 where table1.name = table2.name;
```

Comment: my requirement is second table in my question. Please help with query

Comment: @ashwini..i want output like second table